# How to return the text left of line break

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a Excel sheet, which contains a cell with this content:

```
Text1: "abc" linebreak1  
....  
Text31: "mno" linebreak31  

Text 32: ... linebreak32  
...  
Text50: "xyz" linebreak50
```

No I will readout "mno", which is before the line break 31 in the excel cell.
I've opened my excel file with hex editor and noticed the break line after "o" in the row "Text31"
and used the following formula:

```
MID(CELL,FIND("Text31: ",CELL),FIND("Text31: ",CELL)-
FIND(CHAR(13)&CHAR(10),CELL))
```

but it didn't really work. It returned the two following rows (blank line and "Text32:"-row).

I don't know exactly how I can get back the text left of line break 31. How can I get this text?

Comment: Do you know the English correlates of those Excel functions? Could you please post them if you do?

Comment: @Excellll [One of my favorite bookmarks](http://www.piuha.fi/excel-function-name-translation/index.php?page=english-german.html) :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to extract `mno`, this should work.  Note that `B3` is the text.

**EDIT** Slight mistake in the formula, here's the correction:

`=LEFT(MID(B3,FIND("Text31: """,B3)+LEN("Text31: """),LEN(B3)-FIND("Text31: """,B3)-LEN("Text31: """)),FIND("""",MID(B3,FIND("Text31: """,B3)+LEN("Text31: """),LEN(B3)-FIND("Text31: """,B3)-LEN("Text31: """)))-1)`

Edit 2:
Since it is a bit confusing, here's how I came up with the formula.  I broke everything into steps/pieces and put those into their own cells.  Continued this until I had the correct result.  I was able to construct the complete fromula from this.

Here's how I broke it out, and this you should be able to copy and paste directly into excel.  Put the Original Text in B3, and then paste the following below it (in B4-B11):

```
="Text31: """
=FIND(B4,B3)
=LEN(B4)
=LEN(B3)-B5-B6
=MID(B3,B5+B6,B7)
=FIND("""",B8)
=LEFT(B8,B9-1)
```

Here's my descriptions that you can paste into A4-A11 to help you figure out what the heck you're looking at:

```
Text Prior to 'mno' : 
Start position of Prior Text:
Length of Prior Text:
Length of Original Text - Prior Text - Length of Prior Text:
Remaining Text:
Distance to next ":
Result:
```

Comment: @Robert Have you tried this yet?  I am curious as to whether or not it was helpful.

Comment: @Robert please don't post a question only to never return.  The last time you were seen was 10:53, less than an hour after you posted your question.  It can take people time to work our your soltions, and it's disrespectful to ask a community to work on a solution for you when you had no plans on actually looking at it.  If you come back, do not post another question unless you are going to stick around and wait for people's answers and note when you found a solution.